# Show Pop Up when click on Add to cart checkbox for related products Magento 2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

How to show Pop Up when clicking on Add to cart checkbox for related products Magento 2.1.7?

The pop-up message should be (The product has been added to cart)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the javascript that adds the product to the cart

You could add this to your page and then add some popup code into it

```
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }

        </script>
```